# No component factory found - Navigation not working

Tags: ionic2

Using Ionic v 2.1.12

Exception: No component factory found for DetailsPage

Followed every piece of advice I could find with no luck. The latest fix to this problem suggests adding page class to declarations and entryComponents, but it is not working.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { DetailsPage } from '../pages/details/details';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    DetailsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    DetailsPage
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DetailsPage } from "../details/details";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  template: '<button ion-button block (click)="goToDetails()">Search</button>',
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private nav: NavController) {  }

  goToDetails() {
    this.nav.push(DetailsPage, {  });
  }

}
```

details.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'details-page',
  template: 'details page',
})
export class DetailsPage {

}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. You may consider to update your Ionic2 version.

Comment: In details.ts, can you have a space in the template name? Also I think this should be "templateUrl: details-page". Not sure if that would be a separate issue, or maybe it will help you with this one?

Comment: @IanHolden wouldn't be a problem, the `template` is used for writing html within your component, so this will just output a blank screen showing 'details page'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to replicate this issue. **Your code is correct.**

Running `ionic info` returns (yes the C is actually missing in my console from Cordova)

```
$ ionic info

Your system information:

 ordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.13
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.45
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v4.5.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Best thing to do would probably to reinstall ionic.

`npm uninstall ionic` & `npm install ionic cordova -g`

Then create a new project `ionic start newProject blank --v2 --ts`. Copy and paste your code from this question, run `ionic serve` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks to Ivaro18 for trying to replicate the error and @HadrienTOMA also for suggesting I upgrade Ionic.